# I cannot read XML data from a particular URL

Tags: android, rss

I've been stuck for a while now trying to read XML data from a particular URL. I got a number of material regarding pulling XML Data with SAX and DOM but it doesnt work with my particular URL

Here is the code i tried. This one uses SAX and works perfectly with

```
    TextView name[];
TextView website[];
TextView category[];

try {

/** Handling XML */
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

/** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
URL sourceUrl = new URL(
"http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml");

/** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
}

/** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

/** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
name = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
website = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
category = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];

/** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
name[i] = new TextView(this);
name[i].setText("Name = "+sitesList.getName().get(i));
website[i] = new TextView(this);
website[i].setText("Website = "+sitesList.getWebsite().get(i));
category[i] = new TextView(this);
category[i].setText("Website Category = "+sitesList.getCategory().get(i));

layout.addView(name[i]);
layout.addView(website[i]);
layout.addView(category[i]);
}
```

also included in the code is the XMLHandler class that extends DefaultHandler

```
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    currentElement = true;

    if (localName.equals("maintag"))
    {
        /** Start */ 
        sitesList = new SitesList();
    } else if (localName.equals("website")) {
        /** Get attribute value */
        String attr = attributes.getValue("category");
        sitesList.setCategory(attr);
    }

}

/** Called when tag closing ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name> 
 * -- </name> )*/
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    currentElement = false;

    /** set value */ 
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
        sitesList.setName(currentValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("website"))
        sitesList.setWebsite(currentValue);

}
```

But when i change the url, it returns a XML Pasing Exception = java.net.UnknownHostException: giantstrides.crs.gov.ng and an Unable to start activity error (using Tomcat)

```
    TextView title[];
    TextView description[];

    try {

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        URL sourceUrl = new URL(
                "http://giantstrides.crs.gov.ng/index.php?option=com_ninjarsssyndicator&feed_id=22&format=raw");

        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }

    /** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
    sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

    /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
    title = new TextView[sitesList.getTitle().size()];
    description = new TextView[sitesList.getTitle().size()];
    //category = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];

    /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
    //for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getTitle().size(); i++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        title[i] = new TextView(this);
        title[i].setText("Title = "+sitesList.getTitle().get(i));
        description[i] = new TextView(this);
        description[i].setText("Description = "+sitesList.getDescription().get(i));
        //category[i] = new TextView(this);
        //category[i].setText("Website Category = "+sitesList.getCategory().get(i));

        layout.addView(title[i]);
        layout.addView(description[i]);
```

There is no problem with the URL because it loads the feeds on a browser but i cant get the information i require. Please, i need help, anybody, please..

Gozie